# Spark issues in creating hfiles- Added a key not lexically larger than previous cell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, bulk-load

I am trying to create hfiles to do bulk load into Hbase and it keeps throwing the error with the row key even though everything looks fine.
I am using the following code:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
   .option("header", "true")
   .option("inferSchema", "true")
   .load("data.csv")

import sqlContext.implicits._

val DF2 = df.filter($"company".isNotNull)
  .dropDuplicates(Array("company"))
  .sortWithinPartitions("company").sort("company")

val rdd = DF2.flatMap(x => { 
  val rowKey = Bytes.toBytes(x(0).toString)
  for (i <- 0 to cols.length - 1) yield {
    val index = x.fieldIndex(new String(cols(i)))
    val value = if (x.isNullAt(index)) "".getBytes else x(index).toString.getBytes
         (new ImmutableBytesWritable(rowKey), new KeyValue(rowKey, COLUMN_FAMILY, cols(i), value))
  }
})

rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("HDFS LOcation", classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[KeyValue], classOf[HFileOutputFormat2], fconf)
```

and I am using the following data

```
company,date,open,high,low,close,volume
ABG,01-Jan-2010,11.53,11.53,11.53,11.53,0
ABM,01-Jan-2010,20.66,20.66,20.66,20.66,0
ABR,01-Jan-2010,1.99,1.99,1.99,1.99,0
ABT,01-Jan-2010,53.99,53.99,53.99,53.99,0
ABX,01-Jan-2010,39.38,39.38,39.38,39.38,0
ACC,01-Jan-2010,28.1,28.1,28.1,28.1,0
ACE,01-Jan-2010,50.4,50.4,50.4,50.4,0
ACG,01-Jan-2010,8.25,8.25,8.25,8.25,0
ADC,01-Jan-2010,27.25,27.25,27.25,27.25,0
```

It throws the error as

```
java.io.IOException: Added a key not lexically larger than previous. Current cell = ADC/data:high/1505862570671/Put/vlen=5/seqid=0, lastCell = ADC/data:open/1505862570671/Put/vlen=5/seqid=0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.AbstractHFileWriter.checkKey(AbstractHFileWriter.java:204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2.append(HFileWriterV2.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile$Writer.append(StoreFile.java:992)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2$1.write(HFileOutputFormat2.java:199)
```

I even tried sorting the data but still the error is thrown.

Comment: what is the version of hbase jars are you using?

Comment: @squid i am using hbase 1.2.3 jars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending couple of hours I found the solution, rootcause is that the columns are not sorted.

Since Hfile needs keyvalue in lexicographically sorted order and in your case while writing **`HFileOutputFormat2->AbstractHFileWriter`** found `Added a key not lexically larger than previous. Current cell`. You have already applied sorting at row level once you sort the columns also it would work.

Question here with good explanation [why-hbase-keyvaluesortreducer-need-to-sort-all-keyvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047145/why-hbase-keyvaluesortreducer-need-to-sort-all-keyvalue).

Solution:

```
//sort columns
val cols = companyDs.columns.sorted

//Rest of the code is same

val output = companyDs.rdd.flatMap(x => {
  val rowKey = Bytes.toBytes(x(0).toString)
 val hkey = new ImmutableBytesWritable(rowKey)
  for (i <- 0 to cols.length - 1) yield {
    val index = x.fieldIndex(new String(cols(i)))
    val value = if (x.isNullAt(index)) "".getBytes else x(index).toString.getBytes
    val kv = new KeyValue(rowKey,COLUMN_FAMILY, cols(i).getBytes(),System.currentTimeMillis()+i ,x(i).toString.getBytes())
    (hkey,kv)
  }
})
output.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("<path>"
  , classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[KeyValue],
  classOf[HFileOutputFormat2], config)
```

Answer (score 0):

another scenario: the inserting data existed duplicate row_key

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).